# IBM P5 570 - Scrolling Dots

Tags: ibm

IBM p5 570 server shows dots that move across the screen from left to right, top to bottom upon powering on. It has been doing this for about 20 minutes.

What does this mean?

EDIT: I should clarify, this appears on the operator panel on the front, not on an external monitor.

Comment: Bad display adapter? Bad display cable/connection? Bad display driver? Bad monitor?

Comment: Someone leaning on the "." key of the keyboard? Try and unplug/reconnect the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Service processor does not send data to the LCD panel. Try this: remove both power cords, yank LCD panel out, check the pins, put it back, apply power. If still no display after 20 mins, either of them may be dead. Search the net for "p5 ASMI interface" to get instructions on accessing the service processor.

Answer (score -4):

Did you get it fixed?
I have seen this issue a couple of times,

The dot moving across the control panel display
indicates that the control panel is hung in a reset state.
This symptom might occur if a control panel cable is
incorrectly seated or plugged, if a control panel or cable
is damaged, or if the wrong control panel is installed

Comment: Do not link to your website in a signature.  In fact, [don't include signatures at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).